# I cant connect FTP Server

Tags: ftp, sftp, ftpwebrequest

When I was trying to connect FTP Server in browser or .NET, I can't connect. Bu When I was using Filezilla, I connect, and upload/donwnload files. I tried the following options.

1- When I try with Filezilla, I connect.
2- I did tracert in cmd and I got the error 'Destination host unreachable'. And I opened Telnet Client in windows features. But this time I got error 'Rewuest timed out.'
3- I closed Windows firewall but still the same.

By the way, Ftp server name is starting with sftp. Could it be related to this?
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFTP and FTP are totally different protocols. Filezilla supports both, that's why it connects. SFTP is a protocol that is run over SSH usually on port 22.

FTPWebRequest doesn't support SFTP protocol. There exist many third-party components for SFTP, including our SecureBlackbox ([free license for SFTP](http://www.sftp-net.com/free-sftp-net.html) is available), SSH.NET on codeplex etc..

Comment: Thaks.. i'll search this.